# Is using polyfills to run C# v8 to v11 pattern matching functionality on .NET Framework 4.8 a solid idea?

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching

I would love to use the more advanced pattern matching functionalities that c# version 8 through 11 offer in a .NET Framework 4.8-based solution (which only goes up to c# 7.3 by default).

I see that there are now automatic [polyfilling solutions](https://github.com/Sergio0694/PolySharp/blob/main/README.md) to achieve this very easily! Before I embark in this direction, I wonder if this is a solid solution or is there a good reason why this may lead to instability and weird behavior of the software I'm building (an Office VSTO solution hence the limitation of .NET Framework 4.8 as the highest possible version).

As a developer with limited insight in to what Visual Studio 2022 and its compiler are doing in the background I do not have adequate insight in to whether this could potentially lead to significant issues or not. Thank you for sharing your insights!

Answer (score 3):

You most likely will still need to set [LangVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) for this to work. This itself will be sufficient to enable some of the newer c# features, including pattern matching I think. I have not used PolySharp, but it looks like it just adds some types to enable as many features as possible.

To make this work the compiler has to be able to compile the code to regular .net framework code. I.e. the available features will be of the "syntactic sugar"-kind. Some features will require runtime support, and will not be available unless you update to a newer runtime. So things like generic math will not be available .

Changing langversion is not officially supported. But I have used the latest lang version with .Net 4.8 for about three years now without encountering any issues, but I'm still on VS 2019. In the end it will depend on how risk averse you are.

Comment: Possibly related: [YouTube, Nick Chapsas: "Using Latest C# Features in Any Old .NET Version"](https://youtu.be/RgKa-tjnUMA)

Comment: Fildor yes I found out about the polysharp in his video, but Nick Chapsas likes to do 'unsafe' things with c# in some of his videos ('pushing the envelope'). Nick doesn't answer the question about how solid and reliable this approach is at all.